# How do I determine properties of disks from a live USB?

Tags: bash, disk-image, liveusb, clonezilla, disk-management

I'm currently using Clonezilla to restore previously-created disk images (Windows) to a variety of small computers - an Intel Compute Stick (two versions) and an Asus Vivo Stick. Obviously the image I use to restore depends on which computer the Clonezilla app is attached to - I have three different images that I use. (Is "attached" the right word? Is it a host system?)

I'm creating a standalone application (by modifying a live USB image) that will automatically determine which version of computer is attached, then select the appropriate disk image, and then use clonezilla or something similar to clone that image to the attached computer. Is there a way to differentiate, from within the live USB, which version of computer is attached? `uname` doesn't work, since I'm running from a live USB, and `lsblk` and `fdisk` show me things like disk size and file system type, but not enough information to allow me to figure out which type of computer `/dev/sda` (for example) is. I know there are slight differences in disk sizes between the three computers; do I need to just use that, or is there another, more robust way to find out what I'm working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux has heaps of tools to list the details of the hardware.

Here is a non-exhaustive list : lscpu (CPU), lshw (hardware),
hwinfo (hardware), lspci (PCI), lsscsi (scsi), lsusb (usb),
`inxi -Fx` (detailed hardware), lsblk (block devices),
df (disk space), free (RAM), `/proc` files and more.

For details see
[16 Commands to Check Hardware Information on Linux](https://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-hardware-info/).